# How do you connect an Apple TV to a wireless connection that requires a password after connecting?

Tags: appletv

The wireless router I'm connecting to does not have any encryption.  If you log in from a computer and open a browser, you are prompted with a password request.

How do you access this type of network from an Apple TV?

EDIT: I don't have access to the router or a wired connection; the router belongs to the condo.

Comment: Hi, you might want to log into the router to see if you can save the password. Then I suggest connecting the ATV to a wired connection, and logging into the router and trying to save the password there..

Comment: I think this question is [duplicate with this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51339/how-do-i-add-an-apple-tv-to-hotel-wifi-without-a-browser).