# How do I add an Apple TV to hotel wifi without a browser?

Tags: appletv

I'm staying at a hotel and want to use my Apple TV. My problem is that because there's no browser on the Apple TV I can't get to the proxy web page where I can accept the terms of service.

I found a link explaining a work-around [using a Mac as an ad hoc airport](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1024956), but I don't have a Mac or other wireless router with me, just an iPhone and iPad.

I also found some advice about [spoofing MAC addresses](http://telastipes.blogspot.com/2011/10/apple-tv-without-router-netflix-wifi.html?m=1), but the instructions involved a lot of command line jujitsu that I don't know how to do on iOS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My easiest solution is to get an Airport Express (that is preconfigured with wireless settings and then hooking that up to the Apple TV) and then access the hotel's terms and conditions using your smart phone.

Comment: So for my specific scenario of not having an Airport Express available the answer is it's not possible. Fair enough.

Comment: I know this is an ancient thread. I want to try the Airport Express method and would like to know what you mean by "preconfigured"?

Comment: Remember that apple no longer sell airports.

Comment: @John I think he means that you need to configure it all at home while you have full access to everything, and then bring it to your hotel room ready to go.

Comment: @AdamWuerl Sorry, but I don't consider that *fair* at all!

Answer (score 7):

Use a computer to imitate or “spoof the MAC address” and register the AppleTV hardware address and agree to the terms is the pragmatic manner to join.

Unlike the post you found, however, it can be done much more easily with a MacBook and without much jujitsu.

- First get the MAC address of the Apple TV (available in Settings) and shut it down.
- Then run the following in Mac's terminal app, replacing the MAC address shown with that of your Apple TV: `sudo ifconfig en0 ether 98:01:a7:a1:f6:77`.
- Next confirm the change by running `ifconfig en0 | grep ether`.
- Finally use your Mac's browser to sign-in and bypass the captive portal.

Once that's done disconnect or power off your Mac, plug your Apple TV back in and connect to the network as usual. Instructions here summarized from [Spoofing IoT Device MAC Addresses](https://habd.as/post/spoofing-iot-device-mac-addresses/).

Comment: helped me a lot

Answer (score 5):

I just ran into the same problem.  There's no browser on Apple TV so you can't pass through the authentication page from the hotel.  I found a solution.

I connected my MacBook Pro to the hotel network via ethernet, and used "internet sharing" to share my connection via wifi.  Once connected to Apple TV, I was able to mirror, and use the computer's internet connection to use Apple TV Services.

Answer (score 5):

**Recommended Approach: Add via IT Support**

You don't need to setup your own router, you just need to contact the network's tech support and have them manually add your device via MAC address.

Large chain hotels use companies like [Innflux](http://innflux.com) to deliver HSIA and manage their networks. Typically, these companies will allow you to connect your device to their network, but you must go through them directly. **You simply need to contact their customer service number, and give them the hexadecimal MAC address for the piece of hardware you're trying to connect.**

The MAC address is a unique, factory-set identifier and it's usually printed on the bottom of the hardware or on the box it came in. It looks something like `AC:3A:6B:BE:B7:C1`. If the device has a user interface, you can often get it from a network settings area.

The network technical support phone number is often printed on a card explaining internet access around a guest room's desk. Otherwise, ask a staff member at the front desk for it.

If your device connects to their WiFi network, but doesn't have internet access, you can also copy down the assigned IP address to give to them if you don't know the MAC address.

These companies setup network architecture and use techniques like **port isolation** to increase wireless network security for their clients. Port isolation prevents connected devices from communicating with each other directly.

**Alternative Approach: MAC Spoofing**

In theory, you should be able to connect your Apple TV to the network by [spoofing its MAC address on your laptop](https://gist.github.com/rskelley9/e9fbfe02147cd8f9f7f9), and connecting that device to the network before swapping it out with the Apple TV. This alternative approach may be against your particular service provider's policy and is likely frowned upon. I recommend using the aforementioned first approach, but if you're curious, I created a [walkthrough](https://gist.github.com/rskelley9/e9fbfe02147cd8f9f7f9) for those willing to try this. Spoofing the MAC on my laptop and connecting that way has worked for me multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Went on vacation to Phuket Thailand before I went to the hotel  they had mentioned that Wi-Fi service was being offered at this hotel.

I forgot to check to see if they had an ethernet LAN cable connection, So when I arrived at the hotel I realized that they didn't have this connection  I had taken my airport express to set up a hotspot along with my AppleTV Second Gen to the hotel for watching movies.

As people mentioned above when connecting through settings to the Wi-Fi. It doesn't give you an option to type in a password because everything is done  via the browser.

Well luckily for me I had a jailbroken AppleTV second-generation so I logged into the browser,which is really Couch Surfer Pro went to google.com then hit submit entered  the information my room number and of course password saved it connected to the Internet .

Then hit menu on the remote clicked on Main Menu and Viola you're  connected. But keep in mind the Wi-Fi tends to be slow in the hotel room depending upon your connection speed there hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

Calling the front desk, hotel customer service or isp and having them add your MAC address is the only way to do it without using another device, or a jailbroken apple tv.

Comment: Good luck explaining that to the average hotel front desk clerk ;)

Comment: I've tried explaining this before. I've even had hotel staff deny the existence of any person handling their wifi config.

Answer (score 1):

First check if there is a hard wired Ethernet;  use that if it's possible.

Otherwise use a laptop to spoof the MAC address of the Apple TV.  Do the sign on in the browser; then shut it down and fire up the Apple TV.

Comment: Sadly, this is the best option I've ever found.

Answer (score 1):

You can side-load a web browser on to AppleTV 4 or AppleTV 4K.

Key steps are:

1. Get the source code
2. Compile the code in to a binary (via Xcode)
3. Side-load the binary on to your AppleTV (via Xcode)

macOS, iOS, tvOS developers should find it extremely simple and easy to do. However, non developers will need help or won't be able to use this approach.

Here's the tvOS Browser that I'm using:
https://github.com/jvanakker/tvOSBrowser

I quickly built and loaded it and it works surprisingly well. Granted, I don't use it for anything apart from trying to get through wifi login portals. I actually modified a line so it opens a http:// website by default, which helps too.

Here's a fairly relevant link to a discussion on side-loading apps on AppleTV:
https://initialcharge.net/2017/01/provenance-install-tvos/

Answer (score -1):

None of you are realizing that all you have to do is call the ISP (internet service provider) for the hotel and ask them to put your mac ID for the apple TV into their system for the duration of your stay. The front desk person and sometimes even the manager are not going to even know what you're talking about.  But the ISP has a whole system in place for this.

Comment: I wonder how this would work in practice if the IT infrastructure in the hotel is managed by hotel staff and the ISP is probably not even known to the hotel guest (and vice versa).

Answer (score -2):

Call the hotel's customer service and have them add the MAC address. Done. Or jailbreak it and add a browser.